# Predefined range of date to fill

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, mariadb-10.5

I want to count the number of item by date, but sometimes the table doesn't contains rows with some dates, and I have a hole in the result, like :

```
+------------+--------+
| date       | number |
+------------+--------+
| 2021-03-12 |      1 |
| 2021-03-15 |      1 |
| 2021-03-17 |      1 |
| 2021-03-18 |      1 |
+------------+--------+
```

I would like this result:

```
+------------+--------+
| date       | number |
+------------+--------+
| 2021-03-12 |      1 |
| 2021-03-13 |      0 |
| 2021-03-14 |      0 |
| 2021-03-15 |      1 |
| 2021-03-16 |      0 |
| 2021-03-17 |      1 |
| 2021-03-18 |      1 |
+------------+--------+
```

So, I created a temporary table with `WITH`, it works:

```
WITH recursive Date_Ranges AS (
       select DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS Date
       union
       select Date + interval 1 day
       from Date_Ranges
       where Date < DATE(NOW())
   )
    SELECT *, 0 AS number FROM Date_Ranges
```

Next, I want to retrieve the statistics, I tried with this query:

```
WITH recursive Date_Ranges AS (
   select DATE(NOW()- INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS Date
   union
   select Date + interval 1 day
   from Date_Ranges
   where Date < DATE(NOW())
)
select *, '0' AS value from Date_Ranges
UNION DISTINCT 
SELECT DATE(time) AS date, count(*) AS number
                    FROM my_table
                    WHERE time >= NOW()- INTERVAL 3 MONTH
                    AND time <= DATE(NOW())
                    GROUP BY DATE(ca_time)
```

But the `UNION` doesn't work because the value is different so mysql keep the 2 lines:

```
example:
+------------+--------+
| date       | number |
+------------+--------+
| 2021-03-12 |      0 |
| 2021-03-13 |      0 |
| 2021-03-14 |      0 |
| 2021-03-15 |      0 |
| 2021-03-16 |      0 |
| 2021-03-17 |      0 |
| 2021-03-18 |      0 |
| 2021-03-12 |      2 |
| 2021-03-13 |      6 |
| 2021-03-14 |      7 |
| 2021-03-15 |      8 |
| 2021-03-16 |      9 |
| 2021-03-17 |      5 |
| 2021-03-18 |      0 |
+------------+--------+
```

How the lines with 0 can be merge with the second union ?

Thanks.

Edit:

I tried with this query, but dates without result are not here:

```
WITH recursive dates AS (
   SELECT DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS Date
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Date + interval 1 day
   FROM dates
   WHERE Date < DATE(NOW())
)
SELECT date, COALESCE(COUNT(1), 0) AS number
FROM dates
LEFT JOIN geo
ON dates.date = DATE(geo.ca_time)
WHERE departmentCode = '89'
GROUP BY geo.ca_time
ORDER BY geo.ca_time
```

result:

```
+------------+--------+
| date       | number |
+------------+--------+
| 2021-02-21 |      1 |
| 2021-02-22 |     11 |
| 2021-02-27 |      8 |
...
```

Comment: Use `calendar left join datatable` and `COALESCE(number, 0)`.

Comment: Alternatively, consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: Thanks @Akina, I read the the part "Date Series Generation" on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html but in their example it's a SUM, not a COUNT. And if I try with a COUNT, I never get 0, the min is 1...

Comment: Your `WHERE` condition is removing rows which would have `0` values in them as `departmentCode` will be `NULL`. Move that condition into the `LEFT JOIN` instead i.e. `LEFT JOIN geo
ON dates.date = DATE(geo.ca_time)
AND departmentCode = '89'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNION ALL version

```
WITH recursive Date_Ranges AS (
   select DATE(NOW()- INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS Date
   union
   select Date + interval 1 day
   from Date_Ranges
   where Date < DATE(NOW())
)   
select date, count(*) - 1 AS number
from (
   select date
   from Date_Ranges
   union all
   select DATE(time) 
   from my_table
   where time >= NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
             AND time <= DATE(NOW())
) t
group by date
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b98acc7ab2b603eac3f7905d232fa242)

Comment: Hello,
Thanks for your answer, I tried with my real query but there is a syntax error on the GROUP BY :
```
WITH recursive Date_Ranges AS (
   SELECT DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS Date
    UNION
   SELECT Date + interval 1 day
   FROM Date_Ranges
   WHERE Date < DATE(NOW())
)
SELECT *, count(*) - 1 AS number
FROM (
    SELECT date FROM Date_Ranges
        UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE(ca_time) AS date
    FROM geo
    WHERE DATE(ca_time) >= DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL 3 MONTH
    AND departmentCode = '89'
    AND DATE(ca_time) <= DATE(NOW())
)
GROUP BY date
```

Comment: See edited answer , alias was missing.

Answer (score 0):

join your cte with your table :

```
WITH recursive Date_Ranges AS (
   select DATE(NOW()- INTERVAL 3 MONTH) AS Date
   union
   select Date + interval 1 day
   from Date_Ranges
   where Date < DATE(NOW())
)

select dr.date ,coalesce(sum(t.num),0)
from Date_Ranges dr
left join my_table t
 on dr.date = t.datecol
group by dr.date
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=77c21e8444d96b4eb5f4a3d2327d91b8)*

Comment: Thanks, but the sql result have some holes :
```
+------------+--------+
| date       | number |
+------------+--------+
| 2021-02-21 |      1 |
| 2021-02-22 |     11 |
| 2021-02-27 |      8 |
```

Comment: @Surfoo , that works for me perfectly , see *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.5&fiddle=77c21e8444d96b4eb5f4a3d2327d91b8)*